# Find The value of $a,b,c$.

Tags: derivatives

> If $f(x)=a|\sin x|+be^{|x|}+c|x|^3$ is differentiable at $x=0$, find the values of $a,b,c$.

I know that the derivative exists at $x=0$ *iff* $f'(0^+)=f'(0^-)$, but I can't find $f'(x)$.  Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question suggests there is only one possible set of values for $a$, $b$, and $c$, so you can reverse-engineer the answer on that basis.

Comment: There is not a unique set of $a,b,c$, e.g. $0,0,c$ will do for any $c\in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Deal **separately** with positive and negative $x$. To deal with positive $x$, replace $|x|$ everywhere by $x$, and differentiate as usual.

If $x$ is negative, then $|x|=-x$. To deal with negative $x$, replace $|x|$ everywhere by $-x$, and differentiate as usual. It will make life simpler if you note that $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$ and $(-x)^3=-x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

$f'(0^-)=\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to0^-}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^-}\dfrac{a|\sin(x)|+be^{|x|}+c|x|^3-b}{x}\displaystyle}=\\\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to0^-}\dfrac{-a\sin(x)+be^{-x}-cx^3-b}{x}=g'(0)}$
 where $g(x)=-a\sin(x)+be^{-x}-cx^3.$
Now in a similar way find $f'(0^+)$ and set $f'(0^+)=f'(0^-)$ to find the relation between $a,b,c$ s.t. $f$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We have, for $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$ (which is enough for this problem):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}a \sin(x) + be^x + cx^3,\ \mathrm{if}\ x \ge 0 \\ -a \sin(x) + be^{-x} - cx^3,\ \mathrm{if}\ x < 0\end{cases}, x \in [-\pi, \pi]$$

Then differentiate on $[-\pi, 0)$ and $(0, \pi]$.

Comment: What you wrote is not the piecewise version (sinx)..

Comment: @Josh: Fixed. It does work for $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$ :)